# Parentheses needed after a 'Or' operator

Tags: javascript

Why do you need to add parentheses to the following code for it to work?

```js
let test = 0 || () => {};
console.log(test);
```

```js
let test = 0 || (() => {});
console.log(test);
```

Comment: See *Parsing Order* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Parsing_order

Comment: Because the parser needs you to have those in order to be able to properly parse the code.

Comment: Per firefox, "SyntaxError: invalid arrow-function arguments (parentheses around the arrow-function may help)"

Comment: @AlexK. I must have skipped that part, thanks ... If you can write an answer based on it, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow a single bare argument (`a => a + 1`), the JavaScript grammar gives decreased precedence to arrow function expressions.

In this case, the parser tries to interpret `0 || ()` as the argument of the arrow function. This is obviously impossible, and so parsing fails with a syntax error.